# Is S. S. an abbreviation of scilicet?

Tags: abbreviations

I'm translating the following Latin dedication: "S. S. Theologiae Lectori Primario ad Regium Gymnasium"

"S. S." might be an abbreviation for scilicet (namely, to wit, in particular). Is this  correct?

Would the following be correct: "Namely, Most Excellent Chief Lecturer of Theology for the Royal Gymnasium". Including "Namely" doesn't seem right. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

SS stands (as usual in Christian contexts) for *sanctissimus, -a, -um*, in this case *sanctissimae*:

> To the principal lecturer of the most holy theology ...

Comment: It can also mean *sancti, sanctorum*, "the saints", although that is not what is means in this case. But generally, it means either the superlative or the plural of *S*, *sanctus*.